# How to show that if a positive sequence has no limit points, then the sequence diverges to $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

I was given the hint that I should apply contradiction, and find a bounded subsequence of the sequence. But, I have no idea how to make use of this or how to start the proof.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: A bounded sequence always contains a converging partial sequence, hence a limit point.

Comment: By contradiction. If the sequence does not diverge to $+ \infty$, then there is a bounded subsequence. This has a convergent subsequence: contradiction. Can you fill the details?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 0):

Assume the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$ does not diverge to infinity, i.e. by definition that the following statement:
$$
\forall A > 0 \exists N\geq 0\, \forall n\geq N,\ a_n > A \tag{1}
$$
does not hold. By taking its negation, we have 
$$
\exists A > 0 \forall N\geq 0\, \exists  n\geq N,\ a_n \leq A \tag{2}
$$
Fix such an $A>0$ as garanteed to exist by $(2)$. From $(2)$, you can define by induction a subsequence of $(a_n)_n$, call it $(b_n)_n$, such that
$$
0 < b_{n} \leq A, \, \text{ for all } n\geq 0
$$
*(can you see how?)*. Then, since $(b_n)_n$ is bounded, it will have a limit point (which is then automatically a limit point of $(a_n)_n$ as well), leading to the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Let follow your hint:

Suppose that your sequence $(a_n)$ is not diverging to infinity.
Then, negating the corresponding definition yields:
$\exists A >0, \forall N \in \mathbb{N}, \exists n\in\mathbb{N}, \qquad n>N \wedge a_n < A$.

Let take this constant $A$ and fix it.
Starting with N=1 in the latter property gives us an integer $n_1>1$ such that $a_{n_1}<A$.
Now plug it back as $N=n_1$ to get an integer $n_2>n_1$ such that $a_{n_2}<A$.
You can now construct inductively an increasing sequence of integers $(n_i)$ satisfying $$\forall i, a_{n_i}<A.$$

Then the corresponding subsequence $(a_{n_i})$ has a limit point, which is also a limit point of the initial sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ of a sequence are each a limit of some subsequence (in the extended sense).

Let $(a_n)$ be our sequence, and let $\alpha = \liminf a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} \inf_{k\ge n} a_k$.

Then by the above, there exists a subsequence converging to $\alpha$. Since $(a_n)$ has no limit points in $\mathbb R$, this can only hold if $\alpha =+\infty$.